# mongodb accessing subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection (users) which looks very much the same as mentioned below.

```
db.users.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5773fc2826e0b6cf532569ca"),
        "user" : {
                "login" : "tester"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5773fd6426e0b6cf532569cb"),
        "user" : {
                "login" : "tester",
                "name" : "anil"
        }
}
```

When I do

```
> db.users.find({"user":{"login":"tester"}});
```

I get this as the result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773fc2826e0b6cf532569ca"), "user" : { "login" : "tester" } }
```

However when I do below, I get no records.

```
db.users.find({"user":{"name":"anil"}});
```

>
so my question is why does the second query returns no response ?

Also, based on the examples above, I am even doubting if this is the correct way to access subdocuments ?

Shouldn't the subdocuments be accessed via .notation. Something like below ? (in which case I get the correct output in both the cases)

```
db.users.find({"user.login":"tester"});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773fc2826e0b6cf532569ca"), "user" : { "login" : "tester" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773fd6426e0b6cf532569cb"), "user" : { "login" : "tester", "name" : "anil" } }
```

and

```
> db.users.find({"user.name":"anil"});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773fd6426e0b6cf532569cb"), "user" : { "login" : "tester", "name" : "anil" } }
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also, based on the examples above, I am even doubting if this is the
>   correct way to access subdocuments ?

This is not actually. The first query, `db.users.find({"user":{"login":"tester"}});`, means that you're looking for a `user` that equals to `{"login":"tester"}` object completely, not a user with `login` field equals to `tester`. There is one document that matches with that criteria and that document actually returned as the query result.

Likewise, the second query, `db.users.find({"user":{"name":"anil"}});`, means that you're looking for a `user` that equals to `{"name":"anil"}` object completely. There is no such `user`. There is one document that matches with your query partially but it's not enough.

If you're looking for a `user` with `name` equals to `anil`, use *Dot Notation* to access the sub-document, as you did in your second group of queries.

> Shouldn't the subdocuments be accessed via .notation. Something like
>   below ? (in which case I get the correct output in both the cases)

Yes. this is the correct way.