# updating just one element in a nested json document with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I update just one piece in a document with Mongoose, when the json elements are nested?

I would like to update a document and just set the "darkMode" from false to true, without GETing and PUTing the whole "settins" part. Is this possible with Mongoose?

```
        "settings": {
            "darkMode": false,
            "tipOfTheDay": true,
            "paperFormat": "DINA4",
        },
```

If I PUT this, I will lose everything in the "settings" part of the document:

```
        "settings": {
            "darkMode": true,
        },
```

My NodeJS backend looks like this. I am using the findByIdAndUpdate at the moment. Maybe there is a better method?

```
exports.updateProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
    const profile = await Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true
    });

    if (!profile) {
        return res.status(400).json({success: false});
    }

    res.status(200).json({success: true, data: profile});
}
```

Comment: You need to use `.` notation `settings.darkMode : true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb accessing subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129635/mongodb-accessing-subdocuments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update a field in an embbeded document you must use the a `$set` operator (since your document is an object we are dealing with an object within an object)

From the mongodb documentation :

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents

> Update Specific Fields in Embedded Documents
>   Use dot notation to update values in embedded documents.

So for you, **if we assume that req.body here is `{ darkMode: true }`** it would be

```
    const profile = await Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(
     req.params.id, 
     { $set: { 'settings.darkMode': req.body.darkMode } }, 
     {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true
    });
```

But it all depends on how you send the data from the client, if you send an object containing only modified fields then you must specifically $set them to keep the other value intact like above. To automate this you could also build your query using a fancy loop :

```
let query = { $set: {} }

Object.keys(req.body).forEach(requestBodyKey => {
    let requestBodyFieldValue = req.body[requestBodyKey];
    query.$set[`settings.${requestBodyKey}`] = requestBodyFieldValue;
})
```

Or you can first query your document to get the current_settings, then using javascript you would merge the two objects (e.g. `{...myCurrentSettings, ...myNewerSettings }` [see spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) and then update it to ensure that you keep the previous, untouched, field values.